# On form submit, pass email address from first form to second form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms, the first gets submitted then the page reloads and shows the second. The problem I have is passing the email address from the first form to the second one. What's the best way to do this without interfering with my actions or changing it from POST to GET?

```
    <?php if(!isset($_POST['crowd_email'])){ ?>
      <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding.php' ); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="crowd_email" class="crowd_email" value="" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submit">
      </form>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding-extra.php' ); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="First name">
        <input type="text" name="tel_no" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Telephone number">
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Amount to invest">
        <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submitextra">
      </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking here. Are both these forms in the same script?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The first form displays when the page is initially loaded, then when that form is submitted, the page reloads and hides it... showing the second form instead. Does that make sense? I need to get the email address from the first form into the second somewhere/somehow.

Comment: Ah I got it now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add a hidden field to the second form.

2) Add the value of the email address (submitted from the first form) to the hidden field when rendering the second form.

e.g.

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['crowd_email'])){ ?>

  <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding.php' ); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="crowd_email" class="crowd_email" value="" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submit">
  </form>
<?php } else { ?>
  <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding-extra.php' ); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" name="tel_no" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Telephone number">
    <input type="text" name="amount" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Amount to invest">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST["crowd_email"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submitextra">
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

That way, when you submit the second form, the email field will be submitted along with the rest of the new data.

Comment: No problem. P.S. HTML note..all your `input` fields (apart from mine) are missing closing slashes (since they're not the kind of tags which have separate opening and closing tags). This can occasionally cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a hidden input in the second form containing the email value and give it the value from the first submission

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['crowd_email'])){ ?>

  <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding.php' ); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="crowd_email" class="crowd_email" value="" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submit">
  </form>

<?php } else { ?>

  <form id="form" method="POST" action="<?php require( COMMON_PATH . '/components/crowdfunding-extra.php' ); ?>">

    <!-- New line to hold the email invisbly -->
    <input type="hidden" name="crowd-email" value="<?php echo $_POST['crowd_email']; ?>"/>


    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" name="tel_no" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Telephone number">
    <input type="text" name="amount" class="crowd_email extra-info" value="" placeholder="Amount to invest">
    <input type="submit" class="register-btn" value="Register Interest" name="submitextra">
  </form>

<?php } ?>
```